# Create a trigger instead of create a query with property created_at when create a new node in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, triggers, cypher

I build a social network using Neo4j and I has a problem when creating a new node. I want to every node both has property created_at with values is TIMESTAMP(). I think that 2 way to do this:

1. When create a new node, I add created_at = TIMESTAMP() to thís node.
2. Create a trigger: `call apoc.trigger.add('add-createat-timestamp', 'UNWIND {createdNodes} AS n SET n.created_at = TIMESTAMP()', {phase:'after'})`

And add a question: if I use trigger, I should use `TIMESTAMP()` or   `{commitTime}`

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the example from the [APOC docs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_triggers), which is

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('timestamp','UNWIND {createdNodes} AS n SET n.ts = timestamp()', {phase:'after'});
```

I think that commit time is the time, it took the transaction to commit. So that would not be UNIX time, but time it took the transaction to commit. Check for more info in [Docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionData.html#getCommitTime--).